# I put a hfm and a buttonfield in it,setChangeListener for buttonfield is working only when the focus is on buttonField/hfm in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

After loading the screen If i click on the button directly, the setChangeListener event is not being invoked, rather when the focus is changed to button/hfm, the setChangeListener event is getting called and the desired result is also obtained.

What might be the possible reason and please help me fix this issue...

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(); 
ButtonField buttonF = new ButtonField(ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK); 
buttonF.setLabel("View Key");
FieldChangeListener listeneronClick = new FieldChangeListener() 
{ 
 public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
  { 
   System.out.println("in fieldchange");
     ButtonField buttononClick = (ButtonField) field; 
    buttononClick.setLabel("Hide Key");
     }  
   };  
  hfm.add(buttonF); 
  buttonF.setChangeListener(listeneronClick);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your button like the following

```
ButtonField button = new ButtonField("Ok", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
```

`ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK` Indicates to the button consume the click event.

Comment: I did create my button in the same way.

Comment: HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
ButtonField buttonF = new ButtonField(ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
buttonF.setLabel("View Key");
FieldChangeListener listeneronClick = new FieldChangeListener() {
              public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
               System.out.println("in fieldchange");
                ButtonField buttononClick = (ButtonField) field;
          buttononClick.setLabel("Hide Key");
              }
             };
hfm.add(buttonF);
buttonF.setChangeListener(listeneronClick);

Answer (score 0):

Your `FieldChangeListener` won't do anything because it creates a new button and does not add it to the screen. I'm guessing you just want to change the text on your existing button so try the following code:

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(); 
final ButtonField buttonF = new ButtonField(ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK); 
buttonF.setLabel("View Key");

FieldChangeListener listeneronClick = new FieldChangeListener(){ 

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
    { 
        System.out.println("in fieldchange");
        buttonF.setLabel("Hide Key");
    }  
};  

hfm.add(buttonF); 
buttonF.setChangeListener(listeneronClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

try calling `hfm.setFocus()` before adding `hfm` to the screen manager.